# p-dialog is neither styled as it should nor appears/disappears

Tags: javascript, angular, dialog, modal-dialog, primeng

I want to implement a functionality that when an event in a calendar is dragged and dropped, a dialog appears and a user has to confirm that they really want to postpone this event. Along the way, I encountered the following problem: My `p-dialog` is neither styled as it should by default (for example, as here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo) nor it appears/disappeas upon change in the variable that is supposed to control its visibility - `[(visible)]="displayModal"`.

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-v-3zqtu4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What's wrong here?

EDIT: Updated stackblitz.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on what @captain hak said, the first thing you need to do is import the `DialogModule` as stated. i.e. in `app.module`
 `import { DialogModule } from "primeng/dialog";`

To get the icons working, you'll want to add this to your `index.html`: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />`

I imagine you will be implementing behaviour to change the value of `displayModal` as in the stackblitz there isn't anything at the moment that alters it.

Comment: Apparently I posted the old stackblitz. In the new one, the functionality is started but now there is another error, namely one that says that the package that is in the package.json can't be loaded. Here's the actual one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-v-3zqtu4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This seems to be a wider theme in these stackblitz links, can you ensure you have the right versions of the various packages? primeng's documentation says fullcalendar v4.1.0 and Angular uses core-js v2.6.9 ([according to this](https://github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template/issues/9)). Unless your project is in a mature state, I would recommend updating to the latest stable version of everything, including Angular (v10/11)

Answer (score 1):

you have to import the `DialogModule` from primeng.

In this [stackblitz forked from yours](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-v-twdzh3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)  , you'll see that if you click anywhere in the calendar, the dialog will show up, I let you implement the behavior you need since you have it working now.